# Grails - hide URL paramters after redirect

Tags: url, grails

I'm trying to set a gender filter on a list of users by using the form below for switching search preferences between male and female.

**Filter form:**

```
<div class="datePreferencesContainer">
<g:form controller="browse" action="updateDatingPreferences" method="post"> 
<b>Which Gender:</b>        
<p>
<input type="radio" ${datingPreferences.whichGender==gender.MALE.code() ? "checked" : ""} name="gender" value="${gender.MALE.code()}">Male
</p>
<p>
<input type="radio" ${datingPreferences.whichGender==gender.FEMALE.code() ? "checked" : ""} name="gender" value="${gender.FEMALE.code()}">Female
</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Update"></p>
</g:form>
</div>
```

**(minimal) Browse Controller:**

```
class BrowseController {

  def list() {
    DatingPreferences datingPreferences = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser().datePreferences
    render(
      view: "index",
      model: [
        users: User.list(params),
        userCount: totalCount,
        datingPreferences: datingPreferences,
        gender: Gender
        ]
      )

  }

  def updateDatingPreferences() {   
    try {
      browseService.updateDatingPreferences(params)  
    } catch (ValidationException exception) {
     log.fatal("Exception occured while updating Dating Preferences: " + exception)
    }
    redirect(
      controller: "browse",
      action: "list",
      params: params)

  }

}
```

#### Workflow:

1. I'm opening `http://localhost:8080/foo/browse/list` and see some users.
2. Changing gender from one to another.
3. Then I'm redirected to `http://localhost:8080/foo/browse/list?gender=2&format=`

#### Question:

How can I get rid of the URL parameters, `gender` and `format` that is. I'm using the pagination plugin. <s>and I don't see the pagination parameters in the URL so</s> .I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. What would that be?

#### Thanks!

**Update #1**
The pagination parameters are shown in the URL.

Comment: try using the [forward](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Controllers/forward.html) action instead of using a redirect

Comment: @JohnTheBeloved If I use `forward` insted of `redirect` it goes to `http://localhost:8080/foo/browse/updateDatingPreferences` which is not good. Removed the `params` arg from `redirect` and it's ok now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifically putting params into target URL in your redirect. Just remove it from here:

```
redirect(
  controller: "browse",
  action: "list")
```